# Save data into database android studio

Tags: android

Im having trouble saving data into one of my tables, I have checked everything and its all good, but somehow the inserting method is returning false. No idea whats going wrong, so I came to ask.
Code for saving:

```
private boolean saveUni(String string){
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    APPLICATION uni = new APPLICATION();
    Bundle b2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = b2.getString("applicationId");
    uni.setApplId(id + "_uni");
    if (string == "save"){
        if (SSLSize.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
            uni.setSslSize(SSLSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setSslQuan(SSLQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setSslDateIssue(SSLDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi1.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setSsli(signature);
        }
        if (SShirtSize.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
            uni.setSsSize(SShirtSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setSsQuan(SShirtQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setSsDateIssue(SSDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi2.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setSsi(signature);
        }
        if (LSLSize.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
            uni.setLslSize(LSLSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setLslQuan(LSLQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setLslDateIssue(LSLDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi3.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setLsli(signature);
        }
        if (LShirtSize.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
            uni.setLsSize(LShirtSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setLsQuan(LShirtQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setLsDateIssue(LSDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi4.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setLsi(signature);
        }
        if (TSSize.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
            uni.setTsSize(TSSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setTsQuan(TSQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setTsDateIssue(TSDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi5.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi5.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setTsi(signature);
        }
        if (belt.isChecked()){
            uni.setBelt("Yes");
            uni.setBeltDateIssue(BNBDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi6.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi6.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setBnbi(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setBelt("No");
        }
        if (staffPass.isChecked()){
            uni.setStaffPass("Yes");
            uni.setStaffPassDateIssue(SPDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi7.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi7.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setSpi(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setStaffPass("No");
        }
        if (vest.isChecked()){
            uni.setVest("Yes");
            uni.setVestDateIssue(VestDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi8.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi8.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setVi(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setVest("No");
        }
        if (epaulette.isChecked()){
            uni.setEpaulette("Yes");
            uni.setEpauletteDateIssue(EpauletteDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi9.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi9.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setEi(signature);
        }else {
            uni.setEpaulette("No");
        }
        if (tie.isChecked()){
            uni.setTie("Yes");
            uni.setTieDateIssue(TieDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi10.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi10.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setTi(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setTie("No");
        }
        if (!CShirtCompany.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uni.setcShirtCompany(CShirtCompany.getText().toString());
            uni.setcShirtSize(CSSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcShirtQuan(CSQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcShirtDateIssue(CSDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi11.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi11.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setCshi(signature);
        }
        if (!CPantsCompany.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uni.setcPantsCompany(CPantsCompany.getText().toString());
            uni.setcPantsSize(CPSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcPantsQuan(CPQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcPantsDateIssue(CPDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi12.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi12.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setCpi(signature);
        }
        if (!CVestCompany.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uni.setcVestCompany(CVestCompany.getText().toString());
            uni.setcVestDateIssue(CVDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi13.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi13.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setCvi(signature);
        }
        if (!CTieCompany.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uni.setcTieCompany(CTieCompany.getText().toString());
            uni.setcTieDateIssue(CTDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi14.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi14.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setCti(signature);
        }
        if (!CSuitCompany.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            uni.setcSuitCompany(CSuitCompany.getText().toString());
            uni.setcSuitSize(CSuitSize.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcSuitQuan(CSuitQuan.getSelectedItem().toString());
            uni.setcSuitDateIssue(CSuitDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi15.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi15.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setCsuiti(signature);
        }
        if (lanyard.isChecked()){
            uni.setLanyard("Yes");
            uni.setLanyardDateIssue(lanyardDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi16.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi16.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setLi(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setLanyard(null);
            uni.setLanyardDateIssue(null);
        }
        if (letter.isChecked()){
            uni.setLetter("Yes");
            uni.setLetterDateIssue(letterDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi17.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi17.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setLetteri(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setLetter(null);
            uni.setLetterDateIssue(null);
        }
        if (book.isChecked()){
            uni.setBook("Yes");
            uni.setBookDateIssue(bookDateIssue.getText().toString());
            svi18.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = svi18.getDrawingCache();
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String path = String.valueOf(storageDir);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            signature = BMP.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
            uni.setBooki(signature);
        }else{
            uni.setBook(null);
            uni.setBookDateIssue(null);
        }
    }
    else if (string == "update"){
        ...
    }

    return db.insert_new_uni(uni);
}
```

Code in database:

```
public boolean insert_new_uni(APPLICATION application)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String r;
    try
    {
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_APPL_ID, application.getApplId());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_SIZE, application.getSslSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_QUAN, application.getSslQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_DATE_ISSUE, application.getSslDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getSsli());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_DATE_RETURN, application.getSslDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SSL_RETURN_SIGN, application.getSslr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_SIZE, application.getSsSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_QUAN, application.getSsQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_DATE_ISSUE, application.getSsDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getSsi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_DATE_RETURN, application.getSsDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SS_RETURN_SIGN, application.getSsr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_SIZE, application.getLslSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_QUAN, application.getLslQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_DATE_ISSUE, application.getLslDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getLsli());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_DATE_RETURN, application.getLslDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LSL_RETURN_SIGN, application.getLslr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_SIZE, application.getLsSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_QUAN, application.getLsQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_DATE_ISSUE, application.getLsDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getLsi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_DATE_RETURN, application.getLsDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LS_RETURN_SIGN, application.getLsr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_SIZE, application.getTsSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_QUAN, application.getTsQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_DATE_ISSUE, application.getTsDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getTsi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_DATE_RETURN, application.getTsDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TS_RETURN_SIGN, application.getTsr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_BELT_BUCKLE, application.getBelt());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_BELT_BUCKLE_DATE_ISSUE, application.getBeltDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_BELT_BUCKLE_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getBnbi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_BELT_BUCKLE_DATE_RETURN, application.getBeltDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_BELT_BUCKLE_RETURN_SIGN, application.getBnbr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STAFF_PASS, application.getStaffPass());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STAFF_PASS_DATE_ISSUE, application.getStaffPassDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STAFF_PASS_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getSpi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STAFF_PASS_DATE_RETURN, application.getStaffPassDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STAFF_PASS_RETURN_SIGN, application.getSpr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VEST, application.getVest());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VEST_DATE_ISSUE, application.getVestDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VEST_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getVi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VEST_DATE_RETURN, application.getVestDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VEST_RETURN_SIGN, application.getVr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_EPAULETTE, application.getEpaulette());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_EPAULETTE_DATE_ISSUE, application.getEpauletteDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_EPAULETTE_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getEi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_EPAULETTE_DATE_RETURN, application.getEpauletteDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_EPAULETTE_RETURN_SIGN, application.getEr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIE, application.getTie());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIE_DATE_ISSUE, application.getTieDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIE_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getTi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIE_DATE_RETURN, application.getTieDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIE_RETURN_SIGN, application.getTr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_COMPANY, application.getcShirtCompany());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_SIZE, application.getcShirtSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_QUAN, application.getcShirtQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_DATE_ISSUE, application.getcShirtDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getCshi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_DATE_RETURN, application.getcShirtDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SHIRT_RETURN_SIGN, application.getCshr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_COMPANY, application.getcPantsCompany());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_SIZE, application.getcPantsSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_QUAN, application.getcPantsQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_DATE_ISSUE, application.getcPantsDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getCpi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_DATE_RETURN, application.getcPantsDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_PANTS_RETURN_SIGN, application.getCpr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_VEST_COMPANY, application.getcVestCompany());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_VEST_DATE_ISSUE, application.getcVestDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_VEST_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getCvi());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_VEST_DATE_RETURN, application.getcVestDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_VEST_RETURN_SIGN, application.getCvr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_TIE_COMPANY, application.getcTieCompany());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_TIE_DATE_ISSUE, application.getcTieDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_TIE_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getCti());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_TIE_DATE_RETURN, application.getcTieDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_TIE_RETURN_SIGN, application.getCtr());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_COMPANY, application.getcSuitCompany());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_SIZE, application.getcSuitSize());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_QUAN, application.getcSuitQuan());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_DATE_ISSUE, application.getcSuitDateIssue());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_ISSUE_SIGN, application.getCsuiti());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_DATE_RETURN, application.getcSuitDateReturn());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_C_SUIT_RETURN_SIGN, application.getCsuitr());
        ...
        db.insert(TABLE_UNI,null,contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        return false;
    }
}
```

The code for database runs all until the end, except instead of returning true, it returns false. I have checked all the syntax and data type, its all correct.
These are the red ones in the logcat:

```
10-31 11:43:19.259 3081-3156/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration : 2ms lastUpdatedAfter : 60104 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 257
10-31 11:43:36.203 1511-2322/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2874 [31_Oct_11_43_36.203]
10-31 11:43:42.866 2050-2050/? E/wpa_supplicant: IAPP SNAP_HDR Mismatch
10-31 11:43:44.392 645-645/? E/cnss-daemon: Invalid mac address: 0x556fa59110M
10-31 11:43:44.392 645-645/? E/cnss-daemon: gateway mac address: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x
                                        : 00:00:00:00:00:00
10-31 11:43:57.090 645-645/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
```

Comment: Looks like your code would benefit greatly from refactoring. If its returning false then that means an exception is occuring. How about looking at that exception in detail and see whats going on?

Comment: Meaning? @JoxTraex

Comment: Hm... just ran through the backend of the database, it goes through everything then suddenly stops once its finished

Comment: Man that is a lot of code to look through!! Add `e.printStackTrace();` before returning false so that you can see error message in stack trace. Also try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. If you cannot still solve it, then post the stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the massive amount of code, cant be helped. Just tried printing the stack trace, nothing came up @Nabin Bhandari

Comment: Make sure your logging level in logcat is at least in warn mode. If it is in error or higher, you will not see stack trace by printing it.

Comment: Just edited the question to include the logcat errors @Nabin Bhandari

Comment: That is not a stack trace. Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Comment: Multiple times yea @Nabin Bhandari

Comment: Not really sure whats going on here as I have 3 other tables in the database, all can insert and retrieve smoothly. This table I am working on is not the most complicated one either